# install xp along ubuntu 11.10

Tags: grub2, windows-xp

how to install xp along side of Ubuntu 11.10? I'm not sure of how to take backup of GRUB. I want to restore the menu after installing xp to restore my ubuntu. any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: install xp on different partition and then restore grub using http://askubuntu.com/questions/73937/i-installed-ubuntu-11-to-dual-boot-but-it-still-boots-into-windows-7

Answer (score 2):

Install xp in a different partition and then boot with live cd/usb.

Use `boot-repair` to reinstall grub. Enjoy :)

How to install and use boot-repair : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

Install XP anywhere you want. Start computer from Ubuntu USB or CD. Do following instructions:

1. `sudo fdisk -l` will list you partitions [image]
2. Mount your linux partition to a temp directory with `sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt` (replace ** with your partition)
3. reinstal grub with `sudo grub-install –root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda`
4. Update grub list with `sudo update-grub`